# Docker: Service 'web' failed to build (Django application)

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a Docker container for my Django project. I am using macOS High Sierra. I followed the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#create-a-django-project) 1:1 but I am still running into this issue here. Anyone had this before?

```
Starting docker_5pm_db_1 ... done
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3
 ---> 825141134528
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86fbc1f50cb7
Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cddc69032a83
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5856113960ac
Step 5/7 : ADD requirements.txt /code/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 904ab3d3b831
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in bb0e01c4ca4e
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33266#issuecomment-308977496) I would recommend to rebuild with `--no-cache` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking online](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396#issuecomment-310337418) it seems like your problem is related to your Docker installation, that's messed up. First of all, try to restart Docker. If this doesn't solve your problem, remove the image and try building again with the `--no-cache` flag.

Finally, if none of this works, try cleaning up you Docker environment with:

1 List item

2 click the docker icon in my menubar

3 click `preferences`

4 click the `reset` tab

5 click `remove all data`

Comment: Worked perfectly!